# How to auto insert new line when hit return key between {}

Tags: indentation

When write functino in c.c like this:

`int main(){}`

After I hit return key between {}, it goes like this:

```
int main(){
}
```

How could I get it to work like this:

```
int main() {
   >position of cursor after return<
}
```

Is there any functions or packages can do this?